# Which Android sensor should I use for getting magnetic orientation and inclination towards the horizon?

Tags: android, android-sensors

So far, I've been using `TYPE_ORIENTATION` sensor on Android, even though it's deprecated and it's really inaccurate so I decided I need something better. What I need to get is orientation towards magnetic north (like compass) and inclination towards horizon (angle between where phone's camera is pointing and the horizon).

For compass-like features I don't know if I have to use `TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD` sensor or `TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR`.

And for inclination towards horizon I don't know if I should use `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` sensor or `TYPE_GRAVITY` sensor. gravity sensor seems to be the same as accelerometer, but with only acceleration from gravity, so I suppose I should use gravity sensor for that?

Any kind of answer is useful, even declaring this question as already answered and giving the link. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For the compass like features I would use the TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD. But you have to combine it with the values of the TYPE_ACCELEROMETER as for the compass you also need the current position of the phone relative to the earth (or gravity). Then you have to calculate the rotationMatrix of the phone:

```
SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(this.rotationMatrix,null, this.lastAccelerometer, this.lastMagnetometer);
SensorManager.getOrientation(this.rotationMatrix, this.orientation);

float azimuthInRadiands = this.orientation[0];
float azimuthInDegrees = (float) Math.toDegrees(azimuthInRadiands);
```

This codesnipped is from a Helper I wrote. If you wan´t you can use it to provide the compass so you don´t have to implement it:

[CompassAssistant Helper Class](https://github.com/klein-artur/Simple-Android-Compass-Assistant)

Or you can read the code if you wan´t.

For the inclination towards the horizon you can choose between TYPE_GRAVITY or TYPE_ACCELEROMETER. If you developing for Android above API-Level 9, you should use TYPE_GRAVITY. You should do this because TYPE_GRAVITY gives you only the influence of gravity and accelerometer gives you gravity plus the acceleration of the phone. If you want to use Accelerometer, you should use a high-pass filter to substract the acceleration so you get only the gravity. Otherwhise your inclination would change when the user moves the phone. So it depends on the API level you have to provide.

Hope I could help you.